# MySQL Trigger - Get the difference between old and new value of a json field

Tags: mysql, json, triggers

I have a table with a JSON field containing datas like this :

```
[{"SERIAL":"00001","STATUS":"1"},{"SERIAL":"00002","STATUS":"5"},...]
```

When I modify the status of a serial, I would like to store only the updated element (ie : `{"SERIAL":"00002","STATUS":"6"}`).

Do you know if this is possible with a trigger ?

Thanks !

Comment: As with nearly every JSON-in-MySQL question I read, this would be very simple if you weren't using JSON. Just `UPDATE mytable SET status=6 WHERE ...` I continue to believe nearly every use of JSON in MySQL would be better implemented as normalized tables with rows instead of JSON arrays, and columns instead of JSON documents.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. It will take a little bit of clever coding from you. But why are you tossing out the other JSON objects in the JSON array?  Such a lossy system seems easteful of good data and inefficient.  It seems like it would be easier just to store the update data along with some sort of time stamp and sort by time stamp to get the last update.

Comment: I was not specific enough. I want to insert the modified serial into another table. I found an early solution with json_table but it seems there is a mysql bug with json_table and triggers (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92976)